# How to correctly interpret escape sequences Java

Tags: java, ansi-escape

My Java program seems to have difficulty interpreting the escape characters. The output should be colorful text, but instead ends up like `\u00202b+-+¦¦+-++-+¦¦+-+¦¦¦+-+` instead of the colors.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\gabri\\IdeaProjects\\Atlas\\into.txt"));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try specifying an explicit charset for your FileReader. (whatever your into.txt file's encoding is)

Comment: @OmarAbdelBari I can get it to do it when defining it with "\blablabla" but not when reading with a file, for some reason it reads it as "\\blablabla"

Comment: You are right, surprise to me that it actually allows it. But I guess this depends on who's handling the output.

Comment: How is color information encoded in the file?  In general, Unicode text can contain glyphs that have a defined color (i.e. emojis) but in general text there is no color info.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the encoding of your file is not the default encoding [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), for which `FileReader` is a convenience implementation of `FileInputStream`.

Try a different encoding by using a `InputStreamReader` instead:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
  new InputStreamReader(
    new FileInputStream("C:/Users/gabri/IdeaProjects/Atlas/into.txt"),
    Charset.forName("UTF-16") // find an encoding that works
  )
);
```

There are several [standard charsets](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#standard) from which to choose.

---

Side note: You may use `/` as a path separator for Windows OS file systems - java will figure it out.

Comment: I am not sure I follow here

Comment: He's trying to say try converting the byte contents of your file into a string using a different encoding other than Java's default UTF-8.

Comment: @OmarAbdelBari that would not work for me in the slightest, kept saying it couldn't resolve the constructor

Comment: THat would be odd cause Java is typically backwards compatible and the constructor is `https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html` and `https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html`. Which constructor is it complaining about? Check the documentation for the version you are using. I highly doubt it's not present.

Comment: What version of Java are you using?